# Use ng-model in nested Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, prototypal-inheritance, angular-ngmodel

I have two nested controller in angularjs, and want to use ng-model from outer in inner controller. Suppose this

```
<div ng-controller='outController'>
    // data.Name : from outer controller
    <div ng-controller='innerController'>
         <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-init='name=data.Name'>
         {{data.Name}} // display this scope value
    </div>
 </div>
```

`data.Name` value display in html page but not bind to name ng-model. 
How to bind this value to inner ng-model?

Comment: see [angular guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#scope-inheritance-example)

Comment: @Grundy prototypal inheretance could help him to implement the same thing

Comment: change ng-model to data.Name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow dot rule in this case, so that will allow you to access the parent scope inside the child scope using [**prototypal inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). For using this approach you need to have an object declared in your parent controller like here it should be declared in `outController` then the inner controller will not create a new one, it will use the existing one using `prototypal inheritance`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller='outController'>
    // data.Name : from outer controller
  <div ng-controller='innerController'>
        <input type="text" ng-model='data.Name'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('outController', function($scope){
   $scope.data = {};

   //..other code here ..//

})
```

Comment: i use and proces name ng-model in outer controller.

Comment: @hadi its contradiction between what you are saying.and what you written in question..

Comment: @hadi Glad to help you..Thanks :)