# angularjs calling outer controller from nested ng controllers with ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-change, ng-init

I'm trying to use angularjs to create a page that does the following:

1. Is initially empty, save for a dropdownlist that is automatically
   populated with apps.
2. upon selecting one of those apps, data about it will be called from
   another controller to the page.

I was successfully able to get the dropdownlist to automatically populate.  however, I'm having issues getting it to make the page with ng-change, which I thing is due to the nested ng-controllers.  The chartappsuccessfullogins function is not being called at all in my browser.  Can anyone help me?  Code is below:

My main html page.  Note the use of ng-init:

```
    <div ng-controller="chartsuccessfulapploginsController">
        <div ng-controller="allappsController" ng-init="add()">
            <form name="myForm">
                <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
                <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-change="chartsuccessfulapploginsController.add(value)">
            <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-init="Index = $index"  value="{{data.availableOptions[Index].id}}" ng-model="APPID" >{{data.availableOptions[Index].name}}</option>
        </select>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <p> {{data}}</p>
            <p> {{data.id[0]}}</p>
            <p> {{data.name[0]}}</p>

            <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt><br/>
        </div>
        <p>{{returnCount}}</p>
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <td>{{chartObject.data}}</td>
                <td>{{returnCount}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
    </div>
```

My get all apps controller.  The html page above relies on this to populate the dropdownlist.

```
angular.module('scotchApp').controller('allappsController',['$scope', function($scope){
    var userurl='';
    $scope.add = function(){

        userurl = 'http://localhost:8085/rest/uafapp/appslist';
        var userdata = {};
        var userconfig =
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        };
        var userPostRequest = $.get(userurl, userdata, userconfig);
        var userjson = '{\"USER_DATA_RETRIEVED\" : \"fail\"}';
        userPostRequest.done(function(userdata){

            userjson = JSON.stringify(userdata);
            console.log("userjson :: " + userjson);

            var postResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(userjson);
            $scope.returnName = postResponse['apps'];
            var availableOptionsArray = [];

            for(i = 0; i < postResponse['apps'].length; i++){
                var availableOptions = {};
                availableOptions['id'] = postResponse['apps'][i]['appId'];
                availableOptions['name'] = postResponse['apps'][i]['appName'];
                availableOptionsArray[i] = availableOptions; 
            }
            var returnData = {};
            returnData['repeatSelect'] = null;
            returnData['availableOptions'] = availableOptionsArray;

            $scope.data = returnData;
            console.log($scope.returnData);
            $scope.$apply()
        });

    };
}]);
```

Part of the controller that defines the chart.  It's pretty long, so I didn't include the irrelevant code.

```
   angular.module('scotchApp').controller('chartsuccessfulapploginsController',['$scope','$route','$http','AuthTokenService', function($scope, $route, $http, AuthTokenService){
        var appurl = '';
        var failedappurl= '';

        $scope.add = function(APPID) {

...}
```

Comment: The problem is you're not using controller aliases ex. `ng-controller="allappsController as allapps"`. and your init should then be ` ng-init="allapps.add()"`

Answer (score 0):

Is your `allappsController` within your `chartsuccessfulapploginsController` in your controller file?

It should be inside because `allappsController` is the *child scope*, and `chartsuccessfulapploginsController` is the *parent scope*. You are trying to access the *parent scope* from the *child scope*.

If it is not inside, it thinks that `ng-change="chartsuccessfulapploginsController.add(value)"` is a new controller.

If that is the issue, the fix would be something like this:

```
    angular.module('scotchApp').controller('chartsuccessfulapploginsController',['$scope','$route','$http','AuthTokenService', function($scope, $route, $http, AuthTokenService){
            var appurl = '';
            var failedappurl= '';

            $scope.add = function(APPID) {} ...


            //allappsController inside chartsuccessfulapploginsController
            angular.module('scotchApp').controller('allappsController',['$scope',function($scope){
            var userurl='';
            $scope.add = function(){ ... };

           }]);
}]);
```

Check this out: [Use ng-model in nested Angularjs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034518/use-ng-model-in-nested-angularjs-controller)

Comment: what would the html look like?  where would the ng-model go?

Comment: You are not using the ng-model, the question is similar in the fact that you are both trying to access a outer controller from an inner controller. Your HTML is fine, since your ng-change using hartsuccessfulapploginsController is nested within your inner controller (allappsController). Let me know if I misunderstand your question in your comment.